# when i try $this->Auth->user() it work but when i add id $this->Auth->user('id') it don't work it is null

Tags: cakephp, authentication

$this->Auth->user('id')  always null
appcontrollers code :

```
<?php
 App::uses('AuthComponent', 'Controller/Component');
 App::uses('Controller', 'Controller');
 class AppController extends Controller {
//public $components = array('DebugKit.Toolbar','Session');
  public $components = array(
    'Acl',
    'Flash',
    'Auth' => array(
        'authorize' => array(
            'Actions' => 
       array('actionPath' => 'controllers','action'=>'index')
        )
    ),
    'Session'
);
public $helpers = array('Html', 'Form', 'Session');

public function beforeFilter() {
    //Configure AuthComponent
    $this->Auth->allow();
    $this->Auth->loginAction = array(
      'controller' => 'personnes',
      'action' => 'login'
    );
    $this->Auth->logoutRedirect = array(
      'controller' => 'personnes',
      'action' => 'login'
    );
    $this->Auth->loginRedirect = array(
      'controller' => 'biens',
      'action' => 'index'
    ); }}
```

Personnescontrollers

```
public function beforeFilter() {
parent::beforeFilter();

$this->Auth->allow();
 }

public function login() {
if ($this->request->is('post')) {
     $user = $this->Personne->findAllByLoginAndMdp
  ($this->data['Personne']['login'],$this->data['Personne']['mdp']);

    if ($this->Auth->login($user)) {
   return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl()); 

     } else {
        $this->Session->setFlash(__
       ('Votre nom d\'user ou mot de passe sont incorrects.'));
       }
     }
     }
```

bienscONTROLLERS

```
     public function index( ) {
     $this->Bien->recursive = 0;
      $this->paginate = array(
      'paramType' => 'querystring',
    'limit' => 5
        );
      $biens = $this->paginate('Bien');
      $this->set(compact('biens'));
    $user = $this->Auth->user('id');
    Debugger::dump($user);
     }
```

Personne model`

```
<?php
    App::uses('AuthComponent', 'Controller/Component');
     App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
     class Personne extends AppModel {`
      public function beforeSave($options = array()) {
      $this->data['Personne']['mdp'] = 
      AuthComponent::password($this>data['Personne']['mdp']);
       return true;
       }
```

when i try $this->Auth->user() it work but when i add id $this->Auth->user()'id' it don't work 
Plz what can i do ? can someone help me ?

Comment: when i try $this->Auth->user() it work but when i add id $this->Auth->user('id')it don't work it 's null

Comment: What output do you get when using `$this->Auth->user()` ?

Comment: array(
 (int) 0 => array(
'Personne' => array( 'login' => '*****', 'id' => '2',
'designation' => 'admin',
'dateNaiss' => '2016-03-16','adresse' => 'rue',
   'telFixe' => '266666',
   'telMobile1' => '888888',
   'telMobile2' => '99999',
   'email' => 'wahiba@gmail.com',
   'mdp' => 'wah',
   'lienPhotoPersonnel' => 'wah.jpg',
   'idVille' => '1'
  ),
  'Ville' => array(
   'idVille' => '1',
   'nomVille' => 'Hammamet',
   'lienImageVille' => 'c:/---',
   'affichableVille' => true,
   'codePostalVille' => '8050',
   'idPays' => '1'
  ),
  'BiensPersonne' => array(),
  'Bien' => array()
 )
)

Comment: then shouldn't it be $this->Auth->user(0)['personne']['id'];???